# Possible Issues with Multiple Regression Model?

Tags: regression

[image: Evaluate this multiple regression model, and discuss at least 1 possible issue with the model.]

Evaluate this multiple regression model, and discuss at least 1 possible issue with the model.

Comment: very unclear, but you ever wonder how can two predictor share the same SE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue with model**

The p-value for the S2 suggest that the variable may be insignificant, as the SE(Standard error) is large as compare to t- statistic (representing the mean of the coefficient) is small.

**Important points**

- The Variable S4 is coming out to be very significant as we can see from the p-value, its p-value is very small and Coefficient value is large as compare to others. That, proves our hypothesis regarding "Christmas" that falls in Quarter 4.
- The coefficient for S3 is also significant considering alpha of 5%. but, not as significant as S4.
- We can remove variable S2 and re run the model. and check the coefficient and compare any evaluation metrics e.g. RMSE

Comment: thank you! this is very helpful. at the same time could there also be a i.i.d issue since the samples are taken from different years?